# How to fix 500 error after deploying when DEBUG = False, ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']

Tags: python, django, deployment, digital-ocean, internal-server-error

I am getting a 500 error when I run the server on digital ocean and have set `DEBUG = False` in Settings.py of my django app. I am running the Django server on port 8000, and have had the same issue when using gunicorn. No errors show up when `DEBUG = True`, and my ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']. I have a custom 404 template and handler. The error shows up on any page I attempt to load, except the Django admin page. Please let me know if you have any ideas!!!

Exact error message: `"GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27`

`settings.py` file:

```py
    import os

    from pathlib import Path

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    SECRET_KEY = '**********'
    MAILMAN_PASSWORD = "*********"

    DEBUG = False

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'mysite',
        'webapp',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dashboard_db',
        'USER': 'dashboard_db_admin',
        'PASSWORD': '**********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        }
    }

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = True
    USE_TZ = True

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')

    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webapp', 'static'),
    ]
```

Comment: Do you have any logs from the application?

Comment: `GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1 500 27` is not the error message.  Look in the webserver error log for the real error message.

Comment: check nginx or apche log

Comment: You said no errors are shown either when `DEBUG = True`, but ..  does the site works well? or it is just the same behavior as when `DEBUG = False` ?

Comment: I'm having this problem now.. On digital ocean

Answer (score 0):

set your debug=False then run python manage.py collectstatic and check the logs carefully as sometime bootstrap.bundle.min.js usually reference to bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map which is not among your static files and as such, it will raise an error, so all you have to do is delete the referencing which is usually commented ant the bottom  of the bootstrap.bundle.min.js file and that should fix it